# Code is looping infinitely and I can't figure out why C++

Tags: c++, loops, infinite

there's a section of code in my program that is looping infinitely and I can't for the life of my figure out why. I'm a very novice programmer and any insight would be very much appreciated.
The input I'm focusing on is as follows: (it's not all of the input, but it's enough to throw off my program)

```
A NY 1717 FELSTEIN       SHAZZI
A IN 1764 ALSTOTT        GORDON
A WI 1679 SCANLAN        THOMAS
```

The A means that it's adding the player to the list, and it is, but it's not getting past Mr. Shazzi Felstein.

the culprit code is as follows:

```
class Tournament
{
private:
   RatingAdjustmentLevel chart[MAX_LEVELS];
   PlayerList            allPlayers;
   char command;

   void nametoPlayer()
   {
      string Last, First;
      cin >> Last >> First;
   }

   void processOneCommand(char command)
   {
      if (command == 'A')
      {
         int result;
         string lastName, firstName;
         Player entry, entry2;
         entry.Read();
         result = allPlayers.Add(entry);
         if (result == LIST_FULL)
            cout << "Cannot perform add operation - the list is FULL!";
         else if (result == IN_LIST)
         {
            cout << "Cannot perform add operation - ";
            cout << entry.GetFirst() << " " << entry.GetLast();
            cout << " is already in the list!" << endl;
         }
         else
         {
            cout << "Performed add operation - for ";
            cout << entry.GetFirst() << " " << entry.GetLast() << ".";
            cout << endl;
         }
      }
      else if (command == 'D')
      {
         int result;
         string lastName, firstName;
         Player entry, entry2;
         entry.ReadName();
         firstName = entry.GetFirst();
         lastName = entry.GetLast();
         allPlayers.Remove(entry);
         if (allPlayers.Remove(entry) == true)
         {
            cout << "Performed delete operation - for ";
            cout << entry.GetFirst() << " " << entry.GetLast() << ".";
            cout << endl;
         }
         else if (allPlayers.Remove(entry) == false)
         {
            cout << "Cannot perform delete operation - for ";
            cout << entry.GetFirst() << " " << entry.GetLast() << ".";
            cout << endl;
         }
      }
      else;
   }
public:
   // Reads the rating adjustment chart.
   void readRatingAdjustmentLevelChart()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEVELS; i++)
         chart[i].Read();
   }

   // Reads the players' list to allPlayers.
   void readPlayerList()
   {
      allPlayers.Read();
   }

   // Displays all players in allPlayers.
   void printPlayerList() const
   {
      allPlayers.Print();
   }

   // Processes all transactions until the end of file.
   void processAllTransactions()
   {
      cin >> command;
      while (!cin.eof())
      {
         processOneCommand(command);
         cin >> command;
      }
   }
};   // Tournament

int main()
{
   Tournament tournament;

   tournament.readRatingAdjustmentLevelChart();

   tournament.readPlayerList();

   cout << "\nThe following is an echo of the original "
      << "players' list.\n" << endl;
   tournament.printPlayerList();

   cout << endl << "Processing transactions..." << endl;
   tournament.processAllTransactions();

   cout << "\nThe following is the final players' list." << endl;
   tournament.printPlayerList();

   return 0;
}
```

The issue lies in the processAllTransactions function. The while loop goes infinitely, it never actually recognizes the end of file.
my output is as follows:

```
  13: Processing transactions...
  14: Performed add operation - for SHAZZI FELSTEIN.
  15: Cannot perform add operation -   is already in the list!
  16: Cannot perform add operation -   is already in the list!
  17: Cannot perform add operation -   is already in the list!
  18: Cannot perform add operation -   is already in the list!
  19: Cannot perform add operation -   is already in the list!
  20: Cannot perform add operation -   is already in the list!
  21: Cannot perform add operation -   is already in the list!
```

and so on forever.
It correctly adds the first person to my list of people, and recognizes that he's already there all of the other times it loops, it just never reaches the desired end of file.
Please help! I've trying all sorts of things for hours!

EDIT:
Here is my complete code, so that all the functions can be viewed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int  NOT_FOUND = -1;
const int  MAX_PLAYERS = 25;
const int  MAX_LEVELS = 11;
const int  LIST_FULL = 0;
const int  IN_LIST = 1;
const int  ADDED = 2;

class RatingAdjustmentLevel
{
private:
   int ratingDiff;
   int adjAmtNotUpset;
   int adjAmtUpset;

public:
   void Read()
   {
      cin >> ratingDiff >> adjAmtNotUpset >> adjAmtUpset;
   }
   int  GetDiff() const
   {
      return ratingDiff;
   }
   int GetAdjAmtNotUpset() const
   {
      return adjAmtNotUpset;
   }
   int GetAdjAmtUpset() const
   {
      return adjAmtUpset;
   }
};

class Player
{
private:
   string state;
   int rating;
   string last;
   string first;

public:
   void Read()
   {
      cin >> state >> rating >> last >> first;
   }
   void ReadName()
   {
      cin >> last, first;
   }
   string GetFirst() const
   {
      return first;
   }
   string GetLast() const
   {
      return last;
   }
   int GetRating() const
   {
      return rating;
   }
   void Print() const
   {
      cout << setiosflags(ios::left);
      cout << setw(8) << rating << setw(17) << last;
      cout << setw(18) << first << setw(5) << state << endl;
   }
   bool Equals(const Player& p) const
   {
      if (p.GetFirst() == first && p.GetLast() == last)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }
   void UpdateRating(int points)
   {
      rating += points;
   }
};

class PlayerList
{
private:
   Player list[MAX_PLAYERS];
   int    numPlayers;
   int Find(const Player& p) const
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
      {
         if (list[i].Equals(p) == true)
         {
            return i;
         }
      }
      return NOT_FOUND;
   }


public:
   void Read()
   {
      cin >> numPlayers;
      for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
      {
         list[i].Read();

      }
   }
   int Add(const Player& p)
   {
      if (numPlayers >= MAX_PLAYERS)
      {
         return LIST_FULL;
      }
      else if (Find(p) != NOT_FOUND)
      {
         return IN_LIST;
      }
      else
      {
         list[numPlayers].Read();
         numPlayers++;
         return ADDED;
      }
   }
   bool Remove(const Player& p)
   {
      int index = Find(p);
      if (index == NOT_FOUND)
      {
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         for (int i = index; i < numPlayers; i++)
         {
            list[i] = list[i + 1];
         }
         numPlayers--;
         return true;
      }
   }
   void Print() const
   {
      cout << "The current number of table tennis player is ";
      cout << numPlayers << "." << endl;
      cout << setiosflags(ios::left);
      cout << setw(8) << "RATING" << setw(17) << "LAST NAME";
      cout << setw(18) << "FIRST NAME" << setw(5) << "STATE" << endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
      {
         list[i].Print();
      }
   }
   void ProcessMatchResult(const RatingAdjustmentLevel chart[],
      Player& p1, Player& p2, int& adjAmt)
   {
      int chartIndex = LIST_FULL;
      int decreaseFlip = NOT_FOUND;
      int p1index = Find(p1);
      int p2index = Find(p2);
      int p1rating = list[p1index].GetRating();
      int p2rating = list[p2index].GetRating();
      int difference = p1rating - p2rating;
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEVELS; i++)
      {
         if (abs(difference) > chart[i].GetDiff())
            chartIndex++;
      }
      if (difference >= 0)
         adjAmt = chart[chartIndex].GetAdjAmtNotUpset();
      else
         adjAmt = chart[chartIndex].GetAdjAmtUpset();
      p1.UpdateRating(adjAmt);
      int loser = adjAmt * decreaseFlip;
      p2.UpdateRating(loser);
   }
};

class Tournament
{
private:
   RatingAdjustmentLevel chart[MAX_LEVELS];
   PlayerList            allPlayers;
   char command;

   void nametoPlayer()
   {
      string Last, First;
      cin >> Last >> First;
   }

   void processOneCommand(char command)
   {
      if (command == 'A')
      {
         int result;
         string lastName, firstName;
         Player entry, entry2;
         entry.Read();
         result = allPlayers.Add(entry);
         if (result == LIST_FULL)
            cout << "Cannot perform add operation - the list is FULL!";
         else if (result == IN_LIST)
         {
            cout << "Cannot perform add operation - ";
            cout << entry.GetFirst() << " " << entry.GetLast();
            cout << " is already in the list!" << endl;
         }
         else
         {
            cout << "Performed add operation - for ";
            cout << entry.GetFirst() << " " << entry.GetLast() << ".";
            cout << endl;
         }
      }
      else if (command == 'D')
      {
         int result;
         string lastName, firstName;
         Player entry, entry2;
         entry.ReadName();
         firstName = entry.GetFirst();
         lastName = entry.GetLast();
         allPlayers.Remove(entry);
         if (allPlayers.Remove(entry) == true)
         {
            cout << "Performed delete operation - for ";
            cout << entry.GetFirst() << " " << entry.GetLast() << ".";
            cout << endl;
         }
         else if (allPlayers.Remove(entry) == false)
         {
            cout << "Cannot perform delete operation - for ";
            cout << entry.GetFirst() << " " << entry.GetLast() << ".";
            cout << endl;
         }
      }
      else;
   }
public:
   // Reads the rating adjustment chart.
   void readRatingAdjustmentLevelChart()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEVELS; i++)
         chart[i].Read();
   }

   // Reads the players' list to allPlayers.
   void readPlayerList()
   {
      allPlayers.Read();
   }

   // Displays all players in allPlayers.
   void printPlayerList() const
   {
      allPlayers.Print();
   }

   // Processes all transactions until the end of file.
   void processAllTransactions()
   {
      while (cin >> command)
      {
         processOneCommand(command);

      }
   }
};   // Tournament

int main()
{
   Tournament tournament;

   tournament.readRatingAdjustmentLevelChart();

   tournament.readPlayerList();

   cout << "\nThe following is an echo of the original "
      << "players' list.\n" << endl;
   tournament.printPlayerList();

   cout << endl << "Processing transactions..." << endl;
   tournament.processAllTransactions();

   cout << "\nThe following is the final players' list." << endl;
   tournament.printPlayerList();

   return 0;
}
```

Thank you guys for your help so far!

Comment: change `while(!cin.eof())` to `while(cin)`. There are other possible errors besides `eof`.

Comment: probably `Player::Read()`, or one of the other input function you didn't show, is setting an error flag on `cin`, e.g. if it tries to extract a number and fails.

Comment: By the way, I find it very useful to set `cin.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit )`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/

Comment: I've tried turning the while loop to while(cin), but that only makes it loop once and then not move onto the other people being input, which makes me sad.

Comment: @user3458030: That indicates that the reading of the stream is failing, most probably due to an attempt to parse and `int` where there is none or something alike. You need to *solve* that problem. Changing the loop condition is turning that issue into an infinite loop.

Comment: The problem might be in processOneCommand. You are using many functions whose definitions you have not provided here, for ex. entry.Read(). Might be some mistake in entry.Read() can you provide its code?

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: that sounds like it would work, but I've been tracing my program for hours and haven't made any headway into figuring it out.

Comment: Re. the updated code: you do a lot of `cin >> some_int_variable`. If any of those fail then it will cause your symptoms. You need to check the state of `cin` after those reads, and take action if it failed.

Comment: As a band-aid, you could change the `processAllTransactions` loop to do `if ( !cin && !cin.eof() ) { cin.clear(); cin.ignore(9999, '\n'); }` . This will clera any failed inputs and discard the rest of the failed line. But it would be better to take this action immediately after a failure, otherwise you don't really know "where you are at" relative to what the user typed in.

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace the loop in which you are reading by

```
  while (cin>>command)
  {
     processOneCommand(command);

  }
```

If the input lines are as suggested than better way to process data is

```
  while(cin>>command){
      if(command=='A'){
            cin>>location>>number>>name1>>name2;
      }
      else{
            cin>>read whatever for D
      }

      processOneCommand(all read values);

   }
```

Comment: The loop only executes once if I do that.

Comment: Than surely problem in processOneRead. If processOneRead is guranteed to work the loop will surely work

Comment: My read function is pretty short, I don't think there are problems with it. It simply reads the person's state, number, and names. Then is passes the sorted data to their respective arrays.

Comment: Try my second suggestion